# Avoid/remove web middleware in routes for Laravel >= 5.2.31

Tags: php, laravel

After this [changes](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed) which is Laravel 5.2.31 and above,  all routes in `app/Http/routes.php` will fall under web middleware group.

In `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

**The questions:**

1. What is the easiest/best way to define set of routes without `web` middleware?

One of the use case for this is, declaring routes for stateless api without session middleware which falls under web group middleware

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way I solved this is by editing the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` and having another route files for other group middleware ie api

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);
    $this->mapApiRoutes($router);

    //
}

protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}

// Add this method and call it in map method. 
protected function mapApiRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes-api.php');
    });
}
```

To verify the result, run `php artisan route:list` on terminal and check the route middleware.

**For instance**:

[image: Now I have some route without web middleware which is defined in different file which later called in RouteServiceProvider]

Now I have some route without web middleware which is defined in different file which later called in RouteServiceProvider

**OR**

If you prefer the old features, you can have something like this:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);
    $this->mapGeneralRoutes($router);
}

protected function mapGeneralRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes-general.php');
    });
}
```

Then, in `routes-general.php` you can have multiple middleware groups for different set of routes just like before

Comment: This is actually come out of the box for Laravel 5.3. Now there are two files for web and api