# Laravel store session to redis

Tags: laravel, session, redis

I want to store the session to redis in Laravel.

I was do :
- Change the session driver into 'redis'
- Set my redis server
- and then use this code to store `$req->session()->put($email, json_encode($user));`

The code was run successfully. And it was store to redis.
But, I just simply add the code to 1 function.

Why the other function like example testing()/check(), also setex to redis? I don't even put the code into that function.

Comment: I understand now. Why they always fill the redis for every request. Because on every route(my laravel version is 5.2) on my list, that already include middleware web. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417593/avoid-remove-web-middleware-in-routes-for-laravel-5-2-31

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the session `driver` to redis (in your .env file) and use

```
session(['key', $val]);
```

to store session values

and

```
session('key');
```

to retrieve them

Comment: Yep, that was success.
But, it will also store for every method who hit by users.

I found that, that because 'web' middleware. But now, how to get the data if when i want to get, it also re-set the data to redis. So, if my data before has expired 6090 seconds. After I hit(for get the data), it will re-set again to 7200(default)

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in Redis this way :-

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis; // add in top of controler before class
      or
use Redis;
//put this in function
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->set('boo','Have beer and relax!')
$redis->get('boo');
```